# Truncate and insert into string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string `abcdef`. I need truncate it to the result `def`, then insert into this string a new value `fff` to get the result `fffdef`. So far, I have used substring

```
UPDATE mytable
  SET col1 =
  SUBSTRING(col1, 3, LEN(col1))
from
  mytable
```

But how I can insert to the beginning of the string value?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE mytable
  SET col1 = 'fff' +
  SUBSTRING(col1, 3, LEN(col1))
from
  mytable
```

WARNING: this will change `col1` in all the rows in your table

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be fine . . . without the `from` and using `STUFF()`:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET col1 = STUFF(col1, 1, 3, 'FFF')
```

If you do use a `from` clause, give the reference a different alias:

```
UPDATE t
    SET col1 = STUFF(col1, 1, 3, 'FFF')
    FROM mytable t
```

Although your version does work:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET . . .
    FROM mytable;
```

I consider it to be dangerous, because this would do something much different:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET . . .
    FROM mytable t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need `concat()`, like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
  SET col1 = CONCAT('fff', SUBSTRING(col1, 3, LEN(col1))
from
  mytable
```